# Rounding large integers - objective-c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, rounding

How might I achieve the following in objective-c?

Start with an integer x between 0 and 999,999,999.
And end up with an integer y.

If x is between 0 and 9999, then y = x
Otherwise, x becomes something like 45k (representing 45,000) or 998m (representing 998 million). In other words, use the characters "k" and "m" in order to keep y under or equal to 4 characters long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doesn't round but simply cuts off:

```
NSString *text;
if (x >= 1000000) text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%dm",x/1000000];
else if (x >= 1000) text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%dk",x/1000];
else text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",x];
```

Rounding solution:

```
NSString *text;
if (x >= 1000000) text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0fm",x/1000000.0f];
else if (x >= 1000) text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0fk",x/1000.0f];
else text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",x];
```

If you want greater precision, use `float` and `%.1f` etc.

Comment: will this probably round? for example, 459,861 will be 460k?

Comment: No, it will cut off - shouldn't be hard to make it round (use float or double before division, and format with %0f).

Comment: can you update the code for this? I'm not sure I understand. Thanks!

Comment: Edited to reflect rounding with %.0f. Basically means "floating point number rounded but with zero decimals". Notice the slighty adjusted constants during devision to make it a floating point operation.

Comment: Using this code, I'm getting output of 2m. Could you make it so that I get something like 2.45m? which is still 4 characters.

Comment: Yes, just use %.2f instead of %.0f

Comment: but that might make something like 456.45m

Comment: I thought you asked for 2 digits after the point. :-) You might want to add additional checks for x >= 10000, x >= 100000 etc. and format that with a different number of digits.

Comment: Your code needs to be fixed. On the second if, you need to check if it's bigger than 10k, otherwise the number is ok. He said he wants a maximum of 4 chars. and so until 9999 it's fine, no need of adding the order of magnitude. I think now I understand why you thought my zeros were wrong.

Comment: Good that *you* know what the question was about.

Comment: BTW, there's no need to fix: "under or equal to 4 characters long" was the requirement.

Answer (score 2):

```
thousands = x / 1000;
millions = thousands / 1000;
billions = millions / 1000;

if( billions )
  sprintf(y, "%dB", billions);
else if( millions)
  sprintf(y, "%dM", millions);
else if( thousands )
  sprintf(y, "%dK", thousands);
else 
  sprntf(y, "%d", x);
```

Comment: The modulo operator will not give thousands, millions and billions. You need to use division.

Comment: not sure what you mean, I haven't received nor given a down vote

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *y = nil;

// If Billion
if (x >= 1000000000) y = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0fB", x/1000000000];
// If Million
else if (x >= 1000000) y = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0fM", x/1000000];
// If it has more than 4 digits
else if (x >= 10000) y = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0fK", x/1000];
// If 4 digits or less
else y = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", x];
```

**Update:** Added the missing 'else', otherwise it wouldn't get numbers with less than 4 digits.

Comment: %.0d doesn't make sense. And count the numbers of zeros correctly.

Comment: What is the problem with the zeros? 9 for billion, 6 for million, 3 for thousand? What am I missing?

Comment: Wow...just saw the %.0d, it was supposed to be %.0f, because I've removed the round. It's edited now, thanks!